# How the $scope.$watch works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an application to understand the Angular `$scope.$watch()`. But while doing so faced an issue I couldn't understand.

With the following code, I am expecting that when the value in the `input` box is changing the statement "Data is changing!!" will be logged to the console.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang='en' ng-app="app">
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>My $Scope.$watch demo</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         <div ng-controller="MainController">
           <input ng-model='myData.val'>
           <h1>{{myData.val}}</h1>
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           angular.module('app', [])
           .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
             $scope.myData = {};
             console.log($scope.myData);
             $scope.myData = { val:"Bablo"};
             console.log($scope.myData.val);
             $scope.$watch('$scope.myData.val', function(){
               console.log("Data is changing!!");
             });
           }]);
         </script>  
       </body>
     </html>
```

But I didn't observe what I was expecting, but when I changed the `$scope.$watch()` parameter to `myData.val` (earlier it was `$scope.myData.val`), it started working fine. Why so?

What's the issue here if I pass the whole `$scope.myData.val` instead of just `mydata.val`?

Comment: get rid of `$scope.` in variable string. http://plnkr.co/edit/czqDzJ28TiYA6iDfOvsP?p=preview

Comment: But why its necessary to do so, that's why I am asking!!

Comment: Because the variable is implied to be a property of `$scope` already internally by `$watch`

Comment: Agree but I am not breaking anything by prepending the variable name with $scope.Or I am.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing `$scope.$watch('model_name', function(){})` you are already refering to `model_name` under `$scope`, so when you prepend it with `$scope`, it will look for `$scope.$scope.model_name` i.e `$scope.$scope.myData.val` in your case.
This is the reason why `myData.val` worked and why `$scope.myData.val` didn't.

Comment: @JohnDoe I didn't find this written in documentation explicitly, but yes it can be implied from the documentation that the first parameter of `$watch` i.e. `watchExpression` is the expression/model/data value that you want to watch on your `$scope`. API Doc link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 1):

When you say `$scope.$watch(..` then it means angular is watching for properties inside `$scope`, and since view is bind with `ng-controller` so it is not required in view to append `$scope` before property.

If you append `$scope` to your property the angular looks for new property `$scope.$scope`, which of course doesn't exist., and as soon as your create this (for example by appending $scope in view, then property created and it start watching it. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28633/) and try to connect.